# How to increment max varchar number with +1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT MAX('ABC001') +1
```

I want `ABC002`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need SQL commands to do this?

Comment: What is the point in using `MAX` function?

Comment: Ideally, stop storing *composite* information in a single column. If the prefix varies, store that in a separate column. Keep the numeric data in (probably) an identity column. If *necessary*, then add a computed column that produces this composite output.

Comment: Hi Giorgos, I wnt ABC002 to an increment

Comment: You should rather fix your data model as Damien suggested

Comment: @Asad You have always value like 001, 002 something that which would be increment by 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select concat(left(max(field_name),3),right(max(field_name),3) +1) from table_name
```

Comment: It needs the padding with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Please check Below SQL Command :

```
DECLARE @DATA VARCHAR(256);

SET @DATA = 'ABC001'

SELECT STUFF(@DATA, PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', @DATA), LEN(@DATA), SUBSTRING(@DATA, PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', @DATA), LEN(@DATA))+1) AS DATA
```

Answer (score 0):

If your format is always the same, then you can do :

```
select 'ABC' + right(concat('000',cast(cast(right(max(MY_FIELD),3) as integer) + 1 as varchar(3))),3)
from MY_TABLE
```

You extract the integer part of your max value and increment it by one. Then you convert it to string again, pad it with leading zeroes, and add your prefix.

But it would certainly be very fragile. One single value not following that format and your query will fail.

It would be better to have two different fields : counter and prefix, and compose them on a computed column.

Comment: NO, Format is not same , this will hardcoded not generic

Comment: Then, if your format is not always the same, looks like that you won't be able to do it the way you intended to, and you will need to switch to several columns : prefix, counter_value and number_of_digits.

Comment: I personally have a different SERIES table, where I store the prefix and number of digits of that numeration. So on the MOVEMENTS table, I only need two columns  : serie_id and counter_value. A computed column also gives me that number formatted following the rules on SERIES.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  'ABC'+(REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(CONVERT(Nvarchar(6),MAX(CONVERT(Integer,RIGHT( [COLUMN_NAME] , 2)) )  + 1))) + CONVERT(Nvarchar,MAX(CONVERT(Integer,RIGHT( [COLUMN_NAME] , 3 )))  + 1) )
                FROM [TABLE_NAME]
```

Comment: If you want the 'ABC002' try this                                                                               **`SELECT  'ABC'+(REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(CONVERT(Nvarchar(6),MAX(CONVERT(Integer,RIGHT( 'ABC001' , 2)) )  + 1))) + CONVERT(Nvarchar,MAX(CONVERT(Integer,RIGHT( 'ABC001' , 3 )))  + 1) )`**